# limit size of Queue<T> in C++

Tags: c++, queue, limit, containers

I notice the thread of similar question: [Limit size of Queue<T> in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1292/limit-size-of-queuet-in-net)
That's exactly what I want to do, but I am not using .net but GNU C++. I have no reference to the base class in GNU C++, so java like `super.***()` or .net like `base.***()` will not work. I have been trying to inherit from queue class but it turns out in vain.

What I want to do:
specify the size of the queue, and automatically dequeue when the queue is full. To be specific: if the maximum size of my queue is 2, when I push the 3rd item, the 1st item will be automatically popped out before pushing the new item.

How to implement such a queue?

Thanks.

Comment: You need to explain what you mean by "automatic dequeue" - do you mean discard things at the queue's head?

Comment: @Neil: I was about to ask the very same question, but then I first clikced on the linked posting. `:)`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Make a new class that encapsulates the queue and enforce a size limit in the new class.

Comment: do you mean: creating a new class with a member variable queue?

Comment: @Lily, I believe that is what he is getting at. This is fairly straightforward simply because a queue only really has two important mutators, push_back, pop_front. And in your case if it automatically dequeues you might only need push_back as a public member.

Comment: I disagree with this solution, since it prevents using this queue where a std lib queue is expected (like this: `template< typename T, class C> void f(std::queue<T,C>&)`). OTOH, using `std::queue with a different underlying container will allow to use that queue with sufficiently generic code that expects std lib queues.

Comment: "Make a new class that encapsulates the queue and enforce a size limit in the new class". This means to provide your own implementation of push (and pop) API with a check on the maximum size (in push).

Comment: Might make sense to point out that inheritance can't be used since the STL containers are not designed to be inherited from (they have no virtual functions).

Answer (score 15):

I know you said "automatic", but, to keep things simple: Encapsulate just the `Enqueue()`ing in a local function (no, not clean OO, but it works):

```
Queue<T> myQueue = new Queue<T>();

void addToMyQueue(T param)
{
   myQueue.Enqueue(param); //or push(param)
   if (myQueue.Count > LIMIT)
      myQueue.Dequeue(); //or pop()
}

void main()
{
   addToMyQueue(param);
}
```

Comment: It is a standard queue and it fulfills the purpose (i.e. fixed size of queue). I say this is the most clean solution.

Comment: By the way this is more likely to be Java's format. The class is queue and initialization does not need new, only queue<T> myQueue; will suffice and you need to use push, pop and size instead of those methods.

Answer (score 9):

It sounds like [boost::circuclar_buffer](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/libs/circular_buffer/doc/circular_buffer.html) does what you're looking for:

> **Writing to a Full Buffer**
>
> There are several options how to cope
>   with the case if a data source
>   produces more data than can fit in the
>   fixed-sized buffer:
>
> 1. Inform the data source to wait until
>      there is room in the buffer (e.g. by
>      throwing an overflow exception).
> 2. If the oldest data is the most
>      important, ignore new data from the
>      source until there is room in the
>      buffer again.
> 3. If the latest data is the most important, write over the
>      oldest data.
> 4. Let the producer to be
>      responsible for checking the size of
>      the buffer prior writing into it.
>
> It is apparent that the
>   `circular_buffer` implements the third
>   option. But it may be less apparent it
>   does not implement any other option -
>   especially the first two. One can get
>   an impression that the
>   `circular_buffer` should implement
>   first three options and offer a
>   mechanism of choosing among them. This
>   impression is wrong. The
>   `circular_buffer` was designed and
>   optimized to be circular (which means
>   overwriting the oldest data when
>   full). If such a controlling mechanism
>   had been enabled, it would just
>   complicate the matters and the usage
>   of the `circular_buffer` would be
>   probably less straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that by `Queue<T>` you mean `std::queue<T>`: A queue is just an adapter for some underlying container that's passed at compile-time. You could use a container that already does what you want. The best fit seems to be a circular buffer, if you can find one that supports the operations necessary for `std::queue` (I think that's `push_back()`, `pop_front()`, and `size()`, but I haven't checked).