# How to create a Bitset Array Queue?

Tags: c++, queue, bitset

I am reading in 14 byte messages from a device and I store them in an array of bitsets...

```
bitset<8> currentMessage[14];
```

I want to create a queue of these messages. (Ideally I want the last 10 messages but I think that might be a whole other question? [limit size of Queue<T> in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1273026/limit-size-of-queuet-in-c).)

How can I create this queue?

I tried...

```
std::queue<bitset> buttonQueue;
```

but I received the following errors:

- error C2955: 'std::bitset' : use of class template requires template argument list
- error C2133: 'buttonQueue' : unknown size
- error C2512: 'std::queue' : no appropriate default constructor available

(N.B. I noticed Boost's Circular Buffer, could this be a more suited alternative for what I'm trying to do?)

**I'm pretty new to c++, can anyone help me out?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The template argument need to be a full and complete type. And a templated class like `std::bitset` is not a complete type without its size. So you need to do e.g.

```
std::queue<bitset<8>> buttonQueue;
```

In other words, you need to provide the bitset size as well.

Comment: Don't I need something like std::queue<bitset<8>[14]> buttonQueue; as each message is an array of 14 bitsets each of size 8?

Comment: @KevinPaton Handling of plain arrays can be problematic with templates, and passing around in general. Instead I suggest you use [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array), then you could do e.g. `std::queue<std::array<std::bitset<8>, 14>>`, the queue would contain simple plain objects, that are in essence arrays of bitsets.