# Is there any way to fix the vector size So that it automatically deletes elements from front?

Tags: c++, vector, data-structures

I am trying to figure out the best c++ container before I decide to define my own data structure.

Here is What I am trying to do : 
[image]

For example, In Vectors (C++) Is there any way to fix the size so that I can keep pushing and popping elements from one end and if I push more elements than the size, It should automatically remove the old elements from front.

If not vectors, any thing else ?

Comment: The Boost Library has [`boost::circular_buffer`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/doc/html/circular_buffer.html)

Comment: @jogojapan Thanks! , I think that's exactly what I wanted. But Can I dynamically change the size if required ? . i.e, After using size 7 circular buffer for a while, If I wanted it to resize it to hold 9 elements and continue its behaviour , is it possible ?

Comment: Yes, definitely. The Boost version has a [`resize()`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/doc/html/boost/circular_buffer.html#idp39122944-bb) function. And if you implement the circular buffer yourself, you just have to make sure you use an underlying data structure that is flexible in size, e.g. a `std::vector` rather than a `std::array`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [limit size of Queue<T> in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1273026/limit-size-of-queuet-in-c)

Comment: @xskxzr: Beware, for the highest voted answer of that question is terrible (I just downvoted it). However, the accepted answer is correct (so I just upvoted it).

Answer (score 4):

There is no such container in the C++ standard library, but you can easily create your own by wrapping an existing container. `std::deque` may be appropriate, because it's designed to allow fast insertion and deletion at both ends.

```
template <class T, int MaxSize>
class CircularContainer
{
static_assert(MaxSize >= 0);

public:
    void Add(T const& t)
    {
        if (MaxSize > 0)
        {
            if (size(data) == MaxSize)
            {
                data.pop_front();
            }
            data.push_back(t);
        }
    }

// ...

private:
    std::deque<T> data;
};
```

There are a lot of design decisions to make here, for example:

- Should be the maximum size be completely static, set in the constructor or possibly be modifiable even after a container object has been created?
- Which iterators and references to elements are allowed to become invalid by operations like `Add`?
- Which parts of the wrapped container's interface does your container need to expose? Does it need its own iterator classes, does it have to work with range-based `for` loops, and so on.
- Do you wish to allow a maximum size of zero, and do you need to optimise the corresponding checks with template specialisation or `constexpr if`?
- Should the wrapped container class itself be a template parameter, just like `std::stack` does it?

Most of those design decisions will depend on whether the container will be used in library code or in application code.