# What would be the name of a LIFO structure with the following behavior?

Tags: naming-conventions, stack

I have been documenting myself about stacks, queues and deques for a small project. 
I will be requiring use of both stacks and queues for the project, and another type of structure, something similar to a stack, but that removes the final elements, such as this:

Stack from top to bottom (max 5 elem): [B][C][D][E][F]

Push A, becomes [A]=>[B][C][D][E]=>[F], result:  [A][B][C][D][E]

I have been searching around wikipedia and such, but I don't know how to call this other than "some kind of stack". Results are LIFO, so popping would return A in the example, not F. The code is done as well, so I don't ask for help on that aspect.

My question is simpler: what would be the proper name for this structure?

EDIT: After examining the G5 library as suggested below. I decided to call them "Limited Stacks" or "Lstacks" since it's a name already used in a library. That would make the code more readable. Thanks to everyone!

Comment: You will most likely need to code one yourself.

Comment: you may be interested in the following question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1292/limit-size-of-queuet-in-net

Comment: Freshwire and Russ Cam: It's already coded! I just want to know if it's still named stack or has a different name!

Comment: @roger - I saw that you said that it's already coded, I just thought that the The C5 Generic Collection Library may be useful to take a look at. It's still a stack as far as I know.

Comment: @Russ Cam : Oh! My bad. So they call those "limited stacks" in there? Sounds good enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That looks like a FIFO stack to me.  Item A is your last in, Item F is your first out.

Comment: So there's no difference if I just destroy the last elements to keep it in a fixed size. It is still a "stack"? EDIT: Wait a minute, shouldn't LIFO be A last in, and A last out?

Comment: I believe so,  you're just popping off the last element right before your push a new one. EDIT: sorry you're correct i screwed up the LIFO, this is more of a FIFO situation, first in first out.

Comment: Alright, then just for the sake of differencing I will name the struct "Fstacks" (fix sized stacks)! Thanks! I will keep the question open for a little while just in case, I hope you don't mind!