# Rolling list in .net

Tags: .net, list, collections

Is there any list/collection class in .NET that behaves like a rolling log file? The user can append elements into it, but the list will automatically delete old elements if maximum capacity is exceeded.

I also want access to any element to the list, e.g. list[102], etc.

Comment: Not built-in, but this is trivial in the extreme to implement yourself.

Answer (score 9):

Here is a simple implementation for this:

```
public class RollingList<T> : IEnumerable<T>
{
    private readonly LinkedList<T> _list = new LinkedList<T>();

    public RollingList(int maximumCount)
    {
        if (maximumCount <= 0)
            throw new ArgumentException(null, nameof(maximumCount));

        MaximumCount = maximumCount;
    }

    public int MaximumCount { get; }
    public int Count => _list.Count;

    public void Add(T value)
    {
        if (_list.Count == MaximumCount)
        {
            _list.RemoveFirst();
        }
        _list.AddLast(value);
    }

    public T this[int index]
    {
        get
        {
            if (index < 0 || index >= Count)
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();

            return _list.Skip(index).First();
        }
    }

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator() => _list.GetEnumerator();
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => GetEnumerator();
}
```

Comment: Nice implementation. I suggest "RollingList" name instead of "LimitList"

Comment: Note this class isn't threadsafe. Needs some locks around Add/Indexer methods.

Answer (score 0):

Standart class from Microsoft not exist for you purpose. But you can watch Queue<> class. 
One problem that Queue<> class auto expand. You can resolve it problem in that thread [Limit size of Queue<T> in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1292/limit-size-of-queuet-in-net)

Access to any element able by extended method. For example:

```
LogItem result = collection.Where(x => x.ID == 100).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: The accepted answer in that thread has a serious problem (discussed in the comments)

Answer (score 0):

```
public class RollingWindow<T>: IEnumerable<T>
{
    private readonly T[] _array;

    public RollingWindow(int capacity) => _array = new T[capacity];

    public int Count { get; private set; } = 0;

    private int _headIndex = 0;

    public void Add(T item)
    {
        if (Count < _array.Length)
        {
            _array[Count++] = item;
        }
        else
        { 
            _array[_headIndex++] = item;
            if (_headIndex == _array.Length) _headIndex = 0;
        }
    }

    public T this[int index]
    {
        get
        {
            if (index < 0 || index >= Count) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(index));
            index += _headIndex;
            if (index >= Count) index -= Count;
            return _array[index];
        }
    }

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < Count; i++)
        {
            yield return this[i];
        }
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => GetEnumerator();
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for your answer. Please provide more details about your solution. Code snippets, high quality descriptions, or any relevant information would be great. Clear and concise answers are more helpful and easier to understand for everyone. [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77045362/edit) your question with specifics to raise the quality of your answer. For more information: [How To: Write good answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Happy coding!