# I am looking for "sliding array"

Tags: c#

Is there something that will make it possible in `C#` create array for example `int[6,10]`.
And always when i add new element `[i,0]` all elements in this row will shifted `+1`. And last will remove.

Now I had to do something like this:

```
 array[i, 2] = array[i, 1];
 array[i, 1] = array[i, 0];
 array[i, 0] = value;
```

Could it be better to use for example dictionary with int and List?

Edit:
I not only move this data i will use this data to calculate something. So I think Queue wont be good for this.

I need it for method like this. In this method i do it only for array[6,2].
Now i think i need know more about my history. So i will have array[6,10].
I will check diferent cases and created dependencies. I need something to that it would look as clear as possible and work quickly.

```
 public static double CalculateLastValue(double value, KalmanModel k, int i)
    {
        if (k.LastDistance[i, 0] == 0 && k.LastDistance[i, 1]==0)
        {
            k.LastDistance[i, 0] = value;
            k.LastDistance[i, 1] = value;
        }
        if (k.LastDistance[i, 0] == k.LastDistance[i, 1])
        {

            if (Math.Abs(value - k.LastDistance[i, 0]) > 2 && value < k.LastDistance[i, 0])
            {
                value = k.LastDistance[i, 0] - 2;
            }
            else if (Math.Abs(value - k.LastDistance[i, 0]) > 2 && value > k.LastDistance[i, 0])
            {
                value = k.LastDistance[i, 0] + 2;
            }
            k.LastDistance[i, 1] = k.LastDistance[i, 0];
            k.LastDistance[i, 0] = value;
            return value;
        }
        else if (k.LastDistance[i, 0] > k.LastDistance[i, 1])
        {
            if (value >= k.LastDistance[i, 0])
            {
                if (Math.Abs(value - k.LastDistance[i, 0]) > 2)
                {
                    value = k.LastDistance[i, 0] + 2;
                }
                k.LastDistance[i, 1] = k.LastDistance[i, 0];
                k.LastDistance[i, 0] = value;
                return value;
            }
            else
            {
                value = k.LastDistance[i, 0];
                k.LastDistance[i, 1] = k.LastDistance[i, 0];
                return value;
            }
        }
        else 
        {
            if (value <= k.LastDistance[i, 0])
            {
                if (Math.Abs(value - k.LastDistance[i, 0]) > 2)
                {
                    value = k.LastDistance[i, 0] - 2;
                }
                k.LastDistance[i, 1] = k.LastDistance[i, 0];
                k.LastDistance[i, 0] = value;
                return value;
            }
            else
            {
                value = k.LastDistance[i, 0];
                k.LastDistance[i, 1] = k.LastDistance[i, 0];
                return value;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Unless random access is a requirement it sound like you want a Queue.

Comment: [Queue solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1292/limit-size-of-queuet-in-net) or [List solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14702654/rolling-list-in-net)

Comment: Have look at new C# 8 indices and ranges https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-8#indices-and-ranges

Comment: What you want is too specific: there's not general container for that. You can implement it yourself easily.

Comment: Isn't  [rolling list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14702654/rolling-list-in-net) from A friend link a good dupe target? Or did I miss a requirement?

Comment: At last i would do a lot of operations on this. Sorry i should wrote it.

Comment: why do you want a 2D array? i.e. `int[6,10]`?

Comment: @xdtTransform The only difference is that Queue<T> adds to the end, not the start.. But they could do some transformation when they "use this data to calculate something"

Comment: Because i have 6 similar elements for one object and i had to know their last steps.

Comment: There is no high performance sliding array in the BLC, you will have to create an array and buffer copy it when and item is removed for performance. However in regaurds to performance, it depends if read performance means more to you then adding removing an item

Comment: Dear @JHBonarius i update my post. Maybe now i will more understandable.

Comment: @TheGeneral I think I will spend more time extracting and comparing array elements than updating them. For this I think it should be a array, not a list or queue. So should i stay with array and only do method for update elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no specific data structure for what you want. Furthermore, you already mentioned that adding elements will not occur often... so KIS: keep it simple.

You can write a helper function like:

```
public static void PushElement<T>(ref T[,] arr, int index, T value)
{
    var len1 = arr.GetLength(1);
    Array.Copy(arr, index * len1, arr, index * len1 + 1, len1 - 1);
    arr[index, 0] = value;
}

public static void Main()
{
    int[,] arr = { { 1, 2, 3 }, { 4, 5, 6 } };

    PushElement(ref arr, 1, 7);
```

`arr[1,:]` will now contain 7,4,5.

Answer (score 0):

There are no such data structures in .NET. But that doesn't mean what you need is impossible to build.

You should define your cycle length, `n`, and maintain a `current_index` which wraps around to `0` when it reaches `n-1` index.

```
class wrapping_array
{
    public wrapping_array(int cycle)
    {
         n = cycle;
         array = new int[cycle];
    }

    public int this[int index]
    {
        get => array[index];
        set => array[index] = value;
    }

    int n, index;
    int[] array;

    public int insert(int value)
    {
        array[index++%n]=value;
    }
}
```

Comment: There 100% are plenty of data structures that will do this

Comment: Care to link some in comments?

Comment: [No need](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59048068/i-am-looking-for-sliding-array#comment104337057_59048068)

Comment: Shouldn't the array access in `this[int index]` also be changed to `array[(this.index+index)%n]`? That would probably feel more "natural". And also throw if the requested index is `<0` or `>=n`?

Comment: I'm being annoying but you shouldn't use snake_case in C# if you want to follow the [official guidelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/general-naming-conventions).

Comment: @Corak No need to insert extra checks for range validation, array's indexer will already do that for us. Hence, only insertion requires that round-robin behavior.

Comment: @Joelius Agreed. :) It was for illustration only, I don't expect anyone to include that in production/assignment code.

Comment: @TanveerBadar - yes, you're right, of course. What do you think about using `array[(this.index+index)%n]`, though? How would you reliably get the "most recent" or "oldest" entry?