# How to keep multiple folder choices?

Tags: c#

I have a folder browser button and a combobox which shows selected path. I want it keep previously selected paths. I wrote this code and it works fine. But I wanna know if there is more efficient way to do this.

```
      private void Form1_Load_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
       string hurrem, hurrem2, hurrem3, hurrem4, hurrem5;
        hurrem = Settings.Default["com1"].ToString();
        hurrem2 = Settings.Default["com2"].ToString();
        hurrem3 = Settings.Default["com3"].ToString();
        hurrem4 = Settings.Default["com4"].ToString();
        hurrem5 = Settings.Default["com5"].ToString();


        comboBox2.Items.Add(hurrem);
        comboBox2.Items.Add(hurrem2);
        comboBox2.Items.Add(hurrem3);
        comboBox2.Items.Add(hurrem4);
        comboBox2.Items.Add(hurrem5);
        comboBox2.SelectedIndex = 0;
```

and

```
     private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
                  //..code
            Settings.Default["com5"] = Settings.Default["com4"];
            Settings.Default["com4"] = Settings.Default["com3"];
            Settings.Default["com3"] = Settings.Default["com2"];
            Settings.Default["com2"] = Settings.Default["com1"];
            Settings.Default["com1"] = path1.ToString();

            Settings.Default.Save();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `LimitedStack` from here: [Limit size of Queue<T> in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1292/limit-size-of-queuet-in-net). You could then add methods for serializing/deserializing the data using `Settings.Default`.

```
public void Save()
{
  int i = 0;
  foreach (var item in _stack)
  {
    Settings.Default["com" + i++] = item;
  }

  Settings.Default.Save();
}

public void Load()
{
  for (int i = 0; i < Limit; i++)
  {
    _stack.Add((T)Settings.Default["com" + i++]);
  }
}
```

Storing the items (assuming you have the limited stack saved in a variable called `myStack`):

```
myStack.Push(path1.ToString());
myStack.Save();
```

Adding the items to the combobox:

```
for (int i = 0; i < myStack.Limit; i++)
{
  comboBox2.Items.Add(myStack.Pop());
}
```