# Which data structure allows adding from both sides, but enforces a capacity?

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm, data-structures

I require a data structure that has a `capacity`, but also that allows `adding an item from either the front or the back`. Each time an item is added, one item must be removed from the opposite end. My first thought was that this sound very similar to a `Deque`.

Is there an existing data structure that provides this functionality, or do I have to create it myself? If it does exist, `does the .Net library have an implementation?`

Thanks

Comment: whats the problem with a deque ?

Comment: The "common" `List` allows adding on both sides. You could `while(l.Count > cap) l.RemoveAt(...)`

Comment: For a fixed capacity I would try an array.  Use a pointer to the virtual start.  This way you just update a single value (the virtual start or virtual end).

Comment: Some node-based data structure (e.g. linked list) would be a more logical choice than a contiguous data structure (e.g. array or list) if you're adding/removing from both ends. Otherwise there's going to be a lot of element shifting.

Comment: "Add on both ends" - Deque (not in .Net framework), limited capacity - usually "circular buffer" (not in .Net either)... You'll need to write your own/find other  library - some samples may be found in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1292/limit-size-of-queuet-in-net.

Comment: @itsme86 If you if you use a pointer to virtual start you can avoid element shifting.

Comment: @itsme86 for limited capacity array exposed as circular buffer is at least as easy as linked list (possibly for most people linked list is way beyond regular knowledge - so I'd recommend array).

Comment: @itsme86 No, a properly implemented pointer would not go negative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest that you use a [LinkedList](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/he2s3bh7(v=vs.110).aspx), which gives you all the functionality you need. There are `AddFirst` and `AddLast` methods that let you add items at the front or back, and `RemoveFirst` and `RemoveLast` methods that let you remove from the front and back.

And, of course, there's a `Count` property that tells you how many items are in the list, so you can enforce your capacity requirement.

Answer (score 2):

Not tested but something like this I think would work

```
public class Stack<T>
{
    private T[] arr;
    readonly int m_Size;
    int m_StackPointer = 0;
    public T this[int i]
    {
        get
        {
            if (i >= m_Size)
                throw new IndexOutOfRangeException();
            int pointer = i + m_StackPointer;
            if (pointer >= (m_Size)) pointer -= m_Size;
            return arr[pointer];
        }
    }
    public void AddStart(T addItem)
    {
        m_StackPointer--;
        if (m_StackPointer < 0) m_StackPointer = m_Size - 1;
        arr[m_StackPointer] = addItem;
    }
    public void AddEnd(T addItem)
    {
        arr[m_StackPointer] = addItem;
        m_StackPointer++;
        if (m_StackPointer >= m_Size) m_StackPointer = 0;
    }
    public Stack()
        : this(100)
    { }
    public Stack(int size)
    {
        m_Size = size;
        arr = new T[size];
    }
}
```

Comment: This might be faster than LinkedList as suggested by Jim M.  But LinkedList is 0(1) and less code.

Comment: You code (a kind of circular buffer, `Stack` is wrong term here) is O(1) too.

Comment: @MBo Yes it is O(1) and it might be faster than a LinkedList based solution.

Comment: Yes, this is a Ring Buffer. One of main requirements of the structure is to clearly identify and keep track of a start and an end. I have absolutely no idea how to do this in C#, since raw pointers are not an option. Is sub-scripting really the best choice?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by raw pointers and sub-scripting.  Did you try this code?  You can name the class anything you wish.  The question is tagged C#.

Answer (score 1):

I have decided that the best option is to use an `array of T for the backing structure`, and have a `reference Front and a reference Back` to represent the virtual start and end of the structure. I will also store a direction enum that will effectively indicate which direction the structure is facing(whether the last add operation was at the Front or the Back or a default if no add operations have been performed). `This way, I can also implement an indexer with O(1) complexity`, rather than iterating the collection.

Thanks for all of the responses. For some reason, I thought that I would need to move the data around in the backing structure. I didn't realize that this option is possible in C#.